# Use checkAndMutate (Conditional writes) in BigTable with Apache Beam

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, google-cloud-bigtable, bigtable

I need to write records to BigTable using Apache Beam. But, if a particular row key already exists in the table, the record must not be written. Can I use conditional writes in BigTable for this? I did not find an example for it with Apache Beam in the docs.

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to do this by creating a conditional row mutation that checks for a row regex, and then apply your mutation for the record. Here is code using the Java client (not HBase Java), but for other clients you can find more examples in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/docs/writing-data#conditional) as well as all the necessary packages to include.

```java
String rowkey = "YOUR_ROWKEY";
Mutation mutation =
Mutation.create().setCell(COLUMN_FAMILY_NAME, COLUMN_QUALIFIER, timestamp, VALUE);

Filter filter = FILTERS.key().regex("^YOUR_ROWKEY$");

ConditionalRowMutation conditionalRowMutation =
ConditionalRowMutation.create(tableId, rowkey).condition(filter).otherwise(mutation);
```

Comment: I'm sorry I don't understand how to use this with Dataflow to output a set of ConditionalRowMutations, to be written to BigTable. Could you please share a complete example.

Comment: Have you checked out  Dataflow connector https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/docs/hbase-dataflow-java with the code that Mr. Jacobson included?

Comment: I'm wondering if the key regex filter is useful here. A `pass()` filter will work too.
I'm also wondering if it would help performance if you add a column family in the case if you store multiple kinds in one table...